# How to auto-load everything in a custom library folder in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework, autoload

I have been looking for a solution for this for days and nothing I have tried worked so far :(

We want, in addition to the vendor folder, to have a *lib* folder where to store own libraries which shouldn't be managed by composer. All namespaces/classes should be automatically loaded.

We don't want to make modules out of these libraries, as they are unrelated to the display (we have a database library, for example).

I have tried:

```
application.config.php:
'module_listener_options' => [
    'module_paths' => [
        './module',
        './vendor',
        './lib'
    ],
    ...
 ]
```

But doesn't work... Is what we want even possible? Or is it correct but needs more steps to work? I have found plenty of information on how to load a single class/library that is inside the vendor, but none on how to add a autoload path to autoload everything from a directory outside vendor.

Those libraries we have right now in vendor, the problem we have is that we modify the files regularly and every time we want to run composer, he wants to override all our changes...

What is the correct way to deal with this situation?

Any advice/info would be super helpful!!!

Gioia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add in your root/autoloader.php a statement to load your library. Eventually you have to write a autoload.php at the root of your library.